# Test Message Adapters in Akka Typed

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

I am using Akka Typed (version 2.6.8) and I developed an actor that uses a *message adapter*.

```
object EncoderClient {
sealed trait Command
final case class KeepASecret(secret: String) extends Command
private final case class WrappedEncoderResponse(response: Encoded) extends Command

def apply(encoder: ActorRef[Encode]): Behavior[Command] =
  Behaviors.setup { context =>
    val encoderResponseMapper: ActorRef[Encoded] =
      context.messageAdapter(response => WrappedEncoderResponse(response))
    Behaviors.receiveMessage {
      case KeepASecret(secret) =>
        encoder ! Encode(secret, encoderResponseMapper)
        Behaviors.same
      case WrappedEncoderResponse(response) =>
        context.log.info(s"I will keep a secret for you: ${response.payload}")
        Behaviors.same
    }
  }
}
```

I want to test the effect of creation of the Message Adapter. I see that there is a class in the testkit library, [MessageAdapter](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/testkit/typed/Effect$$MessageAdapter.html) that seems to be a perfect fit to my needs.

However, I can't find anywhere an example of how to use it. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. If you're interested in testing if a message adapter is created by an actor for a particular type `T`, then you can use the [`BehaviorTestKit.expectEffectPF`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/testkit/typed/scaladsl/BehaviorTestKit.html#expectEffectPF%5BR%5D(f:PartialFunction%5Bakka.actor.testkit.typed.Effect,R%5D):R) method.

It follows an example:

```
"EncoderClient" should "send an encoding request to the encode" in {
  val encoder = TestInbox[Encode]()
  val client = BehaviorTestKit(EncoderClient(encoder.ref))
  client.run(KeepASecret("My secret"))
  client.expectEffectPF {
    case MessageAdapter(clazz, _) if clazz == classOf[Encoded] =>
  }
}
```

If the object `clazz` is not of the tested type, the test fails.

Instead, if you're interested in testing that the message adapter works correctly, then, use the strategy suggested by *johanandren*.

Answer (score 1):

The MessageAdapter effect in the behavior testkit only signals that an adapter was created, as a result of a message or actor start. It won't help you with verifying that your adapter works.

You can inject a test probe for the `encoder`, expect a `Encode` message to get a hold of the message adapter `ActorRef` in the message. Something like this:

```
val probe = createTestProbe[Encode]()
val actor = spawn(EncoderClient(probe.ref))
actor ! KeepASecret("hush")
val encodeRequest = probe.receiveMessage()
encodeRequest ! Encoded(...)
// ... verify whatever happens on adapted response arriving...
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. However, my question was: "_I want to test the effect of the creation of the Message Adapter._".

Comment: Sorry, missed that little bit. Then it should be as easy as a: `testKit.expectEffectType[MessageAdapter]` with the behavior testkit. It returns the effect instance so that you assert the message class and potentially invoke the adaptation function in the test.

Comment: What about `testKit.expectEffectPF` ?